# How to Group by last 20 days and do an aggregate function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I can't seem to figure this one out. I'm trying to get the standard deviation of a column for the past 20 days. Here is what I have

```
Model.where('date < ?','2013-03-25')
     .group('date')
     .order('date DESC')
     .limit(20)
     .select('stddev_samp(percent_change) as stdev')
```

However all I'm getting is 20 entries of Nil. I was expecting 1 entry of the standard deviation.

After switching the stddev_samp to sum, I see that I'm getting nil because you can't have a standard deviation on 1 entry. I.e. It is not grouping the 20 as I expected, but calculating standard deviation on each date.

So my question is, how do I get stddev of the last 20 days? I know it's possible to simply choose `select percent_change` and then calculate the standard deviation in ruby, but I assume that the aggregate function stddev_samp should be usable in this case.

I am using rails 3.2 and Postgresql 9.2

Comment: Well, first of all, you want the last 20 *days*, not the last 20 *records*. For that part, I think you want `.where("date >= ?", Time.zone.today - 20.days)`.

Comment: Wait, my last comment might be really stupid. I'll leave it there anyway.

Comment: @JasonSwett Haha no problem...I ordered the date so that the last 20 records are the last 20 days of info

Comment: Yeah, it looks like since you're grouping by date, each record is one day. What I would do here is write the raw SQL that does what you need, and then convert that to ActiveRecord syntax. I also plan to give that a shot myself momentarily.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Ruby guy so I'll explain it in normal SQL:

What you're doing is:

```
SELECT stddev_samp(percent_change) as stdev
FROM tbl
WHERE date < '2013-03-25'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

This calculates the deviation for each day seperately, not for the sum of them, and when you try to get the deviation of only one element you get `NULL`.
Removing the `GROUP BY` would fix it but also would return the result for the whole table not just last 20 entries so we need a subquery:

```
SELECT stddev_samp(percent_change) as stdev
FROM
(SELECT percent_change
FROM tbl
WHERE date < '2013-03-25'
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 20) AS q
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to 'Group By', 'Order by' or sub-selects. Just get the records for the last 20 days and run the aggregate function on them.

Ruby:

```
Model.where('date >= ?', Date.today - 20.days).select('stddev_samp(percent_change) as stdev').first['stdev']
```

SQL:

```
select stddev_samp(percent_change) as stdev 
from <table> 
where date >= now() - interval 20 day;
```

If you want to use the LAST 20 RECORDS, not last 20 days:

Ruby:

```
Model.order('date desc').limit(20).select('stddev_samp(percent_change) as stdev').first['stdev']
```

SQL:

```
select stddev_samp(percent_change) as stdev 
from <table> 
order by date desc
limit 20;
```

Comment: TY, however is there a way to do this with the last 20 entries as opposed to Today - 20? The reason is because this is stock price data and the stocks are not open on saturdays, sundays, holidays, etc. so there are gaps in the days.

Comment: Assuming the DB is MySQL and you just want last 20 records: select stddev_samp(percent_change) as stddev from <table> order by date desc limit 20;

Comment: that may work on mysql...I'm getting a postgresql error saying that `column date must appear in GROUP BY clause or used with an aggregate function` and it points to the `order('date desc')`

Comment: Can you post the entire sql statement you are trying?

Comment: `Model.order('date desc').limit(20).select('stddev_samp(percent_change) as stdev')` gives me that error. It may be important to know that I will also be adding a `.where('asset_symbol = ?, 'yhoo')` to the end of this when I figure it out...but it doesn't look like the `where` is the issue

Comment: Try: Model.order('date desc').limit(20).select('max(date), stddev_samp(percent_change) as stdev')

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the group by since you don't want one value for each date.

also your limit might not work if you have multiple values for a date or have a date missing

try this:

```
SELECT stddev_samp(percent_change) as stdev
FROM
(SELECT percent_change
FROM tbl
WHERE date > now() - interval '20 days') AS q
```